# Window blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prevent users to open tabs/window. I am using the following code:

```
 window.onblur = function() {
   alert(
     'Please do not switch the test window. You may be disqualified from the test'
   );
 };
```

It works fine for window switching but when I try to open/switch tabs it goes in infinite loop repeatedly showing alert box.

I know the reason. Its because the alert box itself triggers the blur event resulting in infinite calls. I don't want to use `console.log` as I want to convey the warning to users.

Comment: You can't *force* this. What about alt+tab'ing? Multiple desktops? Disabled JavaScript?

Comment: I know but something is better than nothing. It works for alt+ tabs though.

Comment: How about using kiosk mode or an HTA

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the window loses focus when it shows the alert, so I was thinking something like this should work (code not tested):

```
var isBlurred = false;

window.onblur = function() {
    if (!isBlurred) {
        isBlurred = true;
        alert('Please do not switch the test window. You may be disqualified from the test');
    }
};

window.onfocus = function() {
    isBlurred = false;
};
```

Comment: Doesn't work mate! Same issue. Somehow I need to exclude blur event for alert box.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue so it's hard for me to test, could you try it again with my updated code? (I moved isBlurred = true before the alert)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to check if the notice is on and also use a small delay when resetting that flag.

```js
var noticeIsOn = false;

window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  if (!noticeIsOn) {
    noticeIsOn = true;
    
    alert('Please do not switch the test window. You may be disqualified from the test');
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      noticeIsOn = false;
    }, 100)
  }
});
```

Comment: On switching tabs, the alert box appears for fraction of a second irrespective of the timeout in milliseconds.